# Сделана попытка выполнить операцию на сокете при отключенной сети при запуске программы бота Telegram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Когда запускаю этот код, проходит буквально 2-3 секунды и вылезают traceback'и

```py
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('мой токен')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    if message.text == "Привет":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Привет, чем я могу тебе помочь?")
    elif message.text == "/help":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Напиши привет")
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Я тебя не понимаю. Напиши /help.")

bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Traceback'и

```
2019-09-09 08:41:54,565 (util.py:65 PollingThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "ConnectionError occurred, args=(MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot%3C974163803:AAHu5avJJuEtsPLtSgeWy8HlnnJUBSBs1tI%3E/getUpdates?offset=1&timeout=20 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03DB55F0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10051] Сделана попытка выполнить операцию на сокете при отключенной сети'))"),)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 160, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "C:\python3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 80, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\python3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 70, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
OSError: [WinError 10051] Сделана попытка выполнить операцию на сокете при отключенной сети

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 603, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\python3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 344, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\python3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 843, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\python3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 316, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\python3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 169, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03DB55F0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10051] Сделана попытка выполнить операцию на сокете при отключенной сети

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\python3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 641, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\python3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 399, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot%3C974163803:AAHu5avJJuEtsPLtSgeWy8HlnnJUBSBs1tI%3E/getUpdates?offset=1&timeout=20 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03DB55F0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10051] Сделана попытка выполнить операцию на сокете при отключенной сети'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python3\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 59, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\python3\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 276, in __retrieve_updates
    updates = self.get_updates(offset=(self.last_update_id + 1), timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\python3\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 246, in get_updates
    json_updates = apihelper.get_updates(self.token, offset, limit, timeout, allowed_updates)
  File "C:\python3\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 180, in get_updates
    return _make_request(token, method_url, params=payload)
  File "C:\python3\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 54, in _make_request
    timeout=(connect_timeout, read_timeout), proxies=proxy)
  File "C:\python3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\python3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\python3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot%3C974163803:AAHu5avJJuEtsPLtSgeWy8HlnnJUBSBs1tI%3E/getUpdates?offset=1&timeout=20 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03DB55F0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10051] Сделана попытка выполнить операцию на сокете при отключенной сети'))
"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 160, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "C:\python3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 80, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\python3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 70, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
OSError: [WinError 10051] Сделана попытка выполнить операцию на сокете при отключенной сети

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 603, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\python3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 344, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\python3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 843, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\python3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 316, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\python3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 169, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03DB55F0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10051] Сделана попытка выполнить операцию на сокете при отключенной сети

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\python3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 641, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\python3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 399, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot%3C974163803:AAHu5avJJuEtsPLtSgeWy8HlnnJUBSBs1tI%3E/getUpdates?offset=1&timeout=20 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03DB55F0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10051] Сделана попытка выполнить операцию на сокете при отключенной сети'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 14, in <module>
    bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
  File "C:\python3\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 389, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(none_stop, interval, timeout)
  File "C:\python3\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 412, in __threaded_polling
    polling_thread.raise_exceptions()
  File "C:\python3\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 78, in raise_exceptions
    six.reraise(self.exc_info[0], self.exc_info[1], self.exc_info[2])
  File "C:\python3\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\python3\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 59, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\python3\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 276, in __retrieve_updates
    updates = self.get_updates(offset=(self.last_update_id + 1), timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\python3\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 246, in get_updates
    json_updates = apihelper.get_updates(self.token, offset, limit, timeout, allowed_updates)
  File "C:\python3\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 180, in get_updates
    return _make_request(token, method_url, params=payload)
  File "C:\python3\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 54, in _make_request
    timeout=(connect_timeout, read_timeout), proxies=proxy)
  File "C:\python3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\python3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\python3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot%3C974163803:AAHu5avJJuEtsPLtSgeWy8HlnnJUBSBs1tI%3E/getUpdates?offset=1&timeout=20 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03DB55F0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10051] Сделана попытка выполнить операцию на сокете при отключенной сети'))
```

Comment: Так а трейсбэки-то где?

Comment: Трэйсбэки добавил

Comment: Зайдите через VPN. Всё заработает.